# how to set path for File Input Stream

Tags: java, file, io

i was trying to use a txt file but i got this eror "FileNotFoundException"
but it was readable and it exist but on line FileInputStream i got that error
whats the matter?

```
        System.out.println(Files.isReadable(Paths.get("I:/Code/Coding/src/Files/" + path + ".txt")));
        System.out.println(Files.exists(Paths.get("I:/Code/Coding/src/Files/" + path + ".txt")));
        FileInputStream f1=new FileInputStream("I:/Code/Coding/src/Files/" + path + ".txt");
        reader = new ObjectInputStream(f1);


java.io.FileNotFoundException: I:\Code\Coding\src\Files\Artists.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at sample.Datebase.Server.readFiles(Server.java:70)
    at sample.Datebase.Server.run(Server.java:99)
    at sample.Datebase.Server.main(Server.java:54)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.Datebase.Server.readFiles(Server.java:94)
    at sample.Datebase.Server.run(Server.java:99)
    at sample.Datebase.Server.main(Server.java:54)
```

Comment: Check the value of path variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and i solved it by using `File` class. Please try this code. maybe your problem will be solved :

```
File file = new File("I:/Code/coding/src/Files/" + path + ".txt");
reader = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
Object o = reader.readObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

The first 3 lines of this code snippet looks ok, ideally it should not throw a FileNotFoundException if the Files.exists, and Files.isReadable gives true.

But you can not use an ObjectInputStream to read a normal text file, as it will look for certain file headers to interpret the java object serialized.

Can you please copy paste the exception trace ?

Comment: i have put there

Answer (score 0):

`FileNotFoundException` - if the file exist but cannot be opened for reading then also throws `FileNotFoundException` exception

Read for Details [FileInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)

First, check the permission of that file. Is it opened for reading or not.

> `public static boolean isReadable(Path path)`: return true if the file
>   exists and is readable but it is not guaranteed; Note that the result of this 
>   method is immediately outdated, there is no guarantee that a
>   subsequent attempt to open the file for reading will succeed (or even
>   that it will access the same file). Care should be taken when using
>   this method in security sensitive applications.